# Python psutil find avaliable ports

Tags: python, port, python-3.4, psutil

I'm trying to find all avaliable ports to connect a computer. I'm using the codes below

```
import psutil
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    print (proc)
    for x in proc.connections():
        if x.status == psutil.CONN_LISTEN:
            print (x)
```

`print(proc)` prints all processes like `psutil.Process(pid=5808, name='pythonw.exe')` and so on. My first question is: What is that `pid` variable? Is that a port?

Second is when I `print (x)` I get an output like `pconn(fd=-1, family=<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, type=1, laddr=('xxx.x.x.x', xxxxx), raddr=(), status='LISTEN')` I understood that `laddr` is standing for local address, but what are other numbers of `laddr`? 'xxx.x.x.x' looks like an IP address but on some outputs it's empty, there are no numbers. Also the second variable of `laddr` is sometimes 3-digits, sometimes 5-digits. What are those numbers stands for?

And my last question, am I on the right way for finding open ports? I'm trying to connect a computer so I'm trying to find open ports on me first.

Answer (score 1):

A `pid` is a "process ID", each process running on your system has a unique identifier, so you can adjust its parameters, or send it signals as it's running like 'terminate', 'stop', 'continue'.

`laddr=('xxx.x.x.x', xxxxx)` is a tuple of IP address and port number.

Running on my system I get the following examples:

`laddr=('127.0.0.1', 3128)`  - listening on IPv4 localhost/loopback only, on port 3128

`laddr=('::1', 3128)` - listening on IPv6 localhost/loopback on port 3128

`laddr=('0.0.0.0', 80)` - listening on any IPv4 address, port 80 (http)

`laddr=('::', 80)` - listening on any IPv6 address, port 80 (http)

If you're doing this to connect to another computer, you won't need to do that - the source port is normally assigned for you when you create an outgoing socket, so you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: So for example, I can connect to a computer via that port numbers eg: 3128? I have the IP address so I'm just checking there is an avaliable port for connection.

Comment: If you're running this on computerA, you're getting the ports that are in use on computerA, so it can tell you what IP address & port combination you can connect to on computerA from somewhere else. If you're making an outgoing connection from computerA, you don't need to worry about the free/used ports on it, just what to connect to

Comment: I actually will try it on command line with `telnet [IP ADDRESS] [PORT]` with this command. I also have a script that I believe it makes telnet connection it's pretty short check it please:http://paste.ubuntu.com/16967685/  So I thought I need port number because of these methods need an open port.

Comment: They need a port on the _destination_, sure. For example, you can `telnet www.google.com 80` to get to the http port (80) of www.google.com and start fetching web pages by hand. The system calls that everything uses to make those network connections will assign you a free port number on your own computer for that connection

Comment: So basically I could use ports that `laddr[1]` for connection, am I right?

Comment: For connections to the computer you've run the psutil script on, yes

Comment: Uhm what you mean psutil script on? Should I make this script keeps running on that computer that I want to connect?

Comment: I mean I'll put this script into that computer and I'll get which ports are avaliable on `laddr[1]`, I get that ports then I'll use them to connect that computer.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be hard to 'connect' to an 'open' port. When a port is opened, whatever program opened the port is listening on that port.

If you want to find ports that are free, your script is working in reverse! You should be looking for ports that are not being used. You can't really have two programs working on the same port. All ports 1-65535 are available to be opened.

If you want to communicate via network, you will have to write a program that sits on computer A that will listen on a port. Then, you have computer B open a connection to computer A on said port. At this point, whatever data you write from B will be sent to the program running on A.

Comment: So basically I have to run a script on computer A, gather the port of it, then when I use `telnet [IP ADDRESS] [PORT]` on command line of my computer, I can communicate with computer A. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, if that script you wrote can interpret telnet.